# jQuery from click() to hover()

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to change the click() to hover().

These are my codes.

HTML:

```
<nav id="menu" >   
<div class="block">
    <A HREF="index.php" class="logo">
        <img src="images/logo.png" />
    </A>
    <div  class="show_sub active05 menu">
        Products & Solutions
    <!--    <div class="tips">
            <img src="images/menutip.png" />
            <span>Who you are?</span>
        </div> -->
    </div>
    <div  class="show_sub active05 menu">Support</div>
    <div  class="show_sub active05 menu">Company</div>

    <div  class="show_sub active05 menu">Investor Relations</div>

    <a href="contact.php" class="active05 menu">Contact</a>                                                             
    <div class="search">
        <form action="product_search.php" method="get" name="computerF" >
        <input type="text" name="keyword" placeholder="Search Product">
        <div class="button" onclick="javascript:document.computerF.submit();">
            <img src="images/search.jpg" />
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>        
</div>     
<div id="menu_down">
    <div class="block"> 
        <div class="name"><span>Products &<br /><b>Solutions</b></span></div>
        <div class="link_block">
            <div class="all_link">
                <!-- START BLOCK : procate1 -->
                <a href="product.php?id={id}" class="{p_active}">{catename}</a>

                <!-- END BLOCK : procate1 -->

            </div>    
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">   
        <div class="name"><span>Support</span></div>
        <div class="link_block">
            <div class="all_link">
                <a href="event.php" class="{event}">Events</a>
                <a href="press.php" class="{press}">Press Release</a>
                <a href="video.php" class="{video}">Video</a>
                <a href="paper.php"  class="{paper}">White Paper & Infographics</a>
                <a href="about_RMA.php" class="{about_rma}">RMA Policy</a>
                <a href="about_green.php" class="{about_green}">Green Policy</a>
                <a href="about_step.php" class="{about_step}">One-stop Global Service</a>    
                <a href="about_care.php" class="{about_care}">Social Care</a>
                <a href="about_dis.php" class="{about_dis}">Disclaimer</a>
            </div>    
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block" >
        <div class="name">
            <span>
            Company
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="link_block">
            <div class="all_link">
                <a href="about.php" class="{about}">Who are we</a>
                <a href="about_do.php" class="{about_do}">What we do</a>
                <a href="about_with.php" class="{about_with}">Careers</a>
                <a href="about_Cert.php" class="{about_cert}">Certification</a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="block three_tree" >  
        <div class="name"><span>Investor<br /><b>Relations</b></span></div>
        <div class="link_block">
            <div class="all_link">
                <a href="investor.php" class="{investor}" >Material Information</a>
                <a href="investor_org.php" class="{investor_org}" >Company Organize and Structure</a> 
                <a href="investor_art.php" class="{investor_art}">Articles of Association</a>
                <a href="investor_Int.php" class="{investor_int}">Internal Audit</a>
                <a href="investor_report.php" class="{investor_report}">Sales Report</a>
                <a href="investor_divid.php"  class="{investor_divid}">Dividend Information</a>
                <a href="investor_proceed.php"  class="{investor_proceed}">Proceedings of General Meeting</a>
                <a href="investor_annual.php"  class="{investor_annual}">Annual Report</a>
                <a href="investor_stock.php"  class="{investor_stock}">Stock Quotes</a>
                <a href="investor_min.php"  class="{investor_min}">Minutes from the Board Meeting</a>
                <a href="investor_investor.php"  class="{investor_investor}">Investor Conference</a>
                <a href="investor_contact.php"  class="{investor_contact}">Contact with Problems Processing</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And jQuery:

```
var nowclick=0;

$(".show_sub").click(function(){
    $(".show_sub").removeClass("show_arrow");
    clearTimeout(menut);
    if(nowclick != $(".show_sub").index(this)){
        $("#menu_down .block").hide();
        $(".show_sub").removeClass("active");
    }
    nowclick=$(".show_sub").index(this);

    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $("#menu_down .block").eq(nowclick).slideToggle();
    $(this).addClass("show_arrow");
});

$("#menu #menu_down .block").hover(function(){
    clearTimeout(menut);
},function(){
    menut=setTimeout(function(){
        $(".show_sub").removeClass("show_arrow");
        $("#menu_down .block").hide('blind',500);
        $(".show_sub").removeClass("active");
    }, 880);
});
```

It's the original code and I have tried some changes, but it didn't work.
For sure, I can't just change it to hover().

Comment: To be honest you can do this all with CSS and shouldn't need to touch jQuery. You should also use the unordered lists in HTML `<ul>` and `<li>` instead of using divs for your menu.

Comment: If I don't change the HTML codes, could you guide me how to do it via CSS?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just change click to hover, see console in the snippet

```js
var nowclick=0;

              $(".show_sub").hover(function(){
                console.log('hovered')
                $(".show_sub").removeClass("show_arrow");
                 clearTimeout(menut);
                if(nowclick != $(".show_sub").index(this)){
                  $("#menu_down .block").hide();
                  $(".show_sub").removeClass("active");
                }
                nowclick=$(".show_sub").index(this);

                $(this).toggleClass("active");
                $("#menu_down .block").eq(nowclick).slideToggle();
                $(this).addClass("show_arrow");
              });



              $("#menu #menu_down .block").hover(function(){

                clearTimeout(menut);

              },function(){

                 menut=setTimeout(function(){
                  $(".show_sub").removeClass("show_arrow");
                  $("#menu_down .block").hide('blind',500);
                  $(".show_sub").removeClass("active");

                 }, 880);


              });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="menu" >   
<div class="block">
    <A HREF="index.php" class="logo">
        <img src="images/logo.png" />
    </A>
    <div  class="show_sub active05 menu">
        Products & Solutions
    <!--    <div class="tips">
            <img src="images/menutip.png" />
            <span>Who you are?</span>
        </div> -->
    </div>
    <div  class="show_sub active05 menu">Support</div>
    <div  class="show_sub active05 menu">Company</div>

    <div  class="show_sub active05 menu">Investor Relations</div>

    <a href="contact.php" class="active05 menu">Contact</a>                                                             
    <div class="search">
        <form action="product_search.php" method="get" name="computerF" >
        <input type="text" name="keyword" placeholder="Search Product">
        <div class="button" onclick="javascript:document.computerF.submit();">
            <img src="images/search.jpg" />
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>        
</div>     
<div id="menu_down">
    <div class="block"> 
        <div class="name"><span>Products &<br /><b>Solutions</b></span></div>
        <div class="link_block">
            <div class="all_link">
                <!-- START BLOCK : procate1 -->
                <a href="product.php?id={id}" class="{p_active}">{catename}</a>

                <!-- END BLOCK : procate1 -->

            </div>    
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">   
        <div class="name"><span>Support</span></div>
        <div class="link_block">
            <div class="all_link">
                <a href="event.php" class="{event}">Events</a>
                <a href="press.php" class="{press}">Press Release</a>
                <a href="video.php" class="{video}">Video</a>
                <a href="paper.php"  class="{paper}">White Paper & Infographics</a>
                <a href="about_RMA.php" class="{about_rma}">RMA Policy</a>
                <a href="about_green.php" class="{about_green}">Green Policy</a>
                <a href="about_step.php" class="{about_step}">One-stop Global Service</a>    
                <a href="about_care.php" class="{about_care}">Social Care</a>
                <a href="about_dis.php" class="{about_dis}">Disclaimer</a>
            </div>    
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block" >
        <div class="name">
            <span>
            Company
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="link_block">
            <div class="all_link">
                <a href="about.php" class="{about}">Who are we</a>
                <a href="about_do.php" class="{about_do}">What we do</a>
                <a href="about_with.php" class="{about_with}">Careers</a>
                <a href="about_Cert.php" class="{about_cert}">Certification</a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="block three_tree" >  
        <div class="name"><span>Investor<br /><b>Relations</b></span></div>
        <div class="link_block">
            <div class="all_link">
                <a href="investor.php" class="{investor}" >Material Information</a>
                <a href="investor_org.php" class="{investor_org}" >Company Organize and Structure</a> 
                <a href="investor_art.php" class="{investor_art}">Articles of Association</a>
                <a href="investor_Int.php" class="{investor_int}">Internal Audit</a>
                <a href="investor_report.php" class="{investor_report}">Sales Report</a>
                <a href="investor_divid.php"  class="{investor_divid}">Dividend Information</a>
                <a href="investor_proceed.php"  class="{investor_proceed}">Proceedings of General Meeting</a>
                <a href="investor_annual.php"  class="{investor_annual}">Annual Report</a>
                <a href="investor_stock.php"  class="{investor_stock}">Stock Quotes</a>
                <a href="investor_min.php"  class="{investor_min}">Minutes from the Board Meeting</a>
                <a href="investor_investor.php"  class="{investor_investor}">Investor Conference</a>
                <a href="investor_contact.php"  class="{investor_contact}">Contact with Problems Processing</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work, if I just change the method from click to hover. when I move the mouse to the sub menu, the sub menu will be disappeared.